# The square is not a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, submanifold

Leb $X$ be the square in $\mathbb{R}^2$

$
X = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : |x| + |y| = 1\}
$

It's so easy to show that $X$ is a differentiable manifold of dimension one. But, it's not possible that $X$ be a regular submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and I dont know prove it.

Answer (score 4):

Assume that $X$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $v$ be a vertex of the square $X$, then the tangent space of $X$ at $v$ should be one-dimensional$^1$, but $T_vX$ is seen to be zero-dimensional$^2$, whence a contradiction.

Another way to see it without (explicitely) using tangent spaces is that it cannot exists a regular parametrization of $X$ near $v$, such a parametrization must have a vanishing derivative at $v$, which prevents it to be an immersion, whence a contradiction.

<sub>$^1$ A zero-dimensional submanifold is discrete and a two-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is locally open, but $X$ is none of them, so that it is one-dimensional.</sub>

<sub>$^2$ A smooth curve drawn on $X$ passing through $v$ at $t=0$ must have a vanishing derivative at $t=0$.</sub>

Comment: sorry... can you explain me a little more? why the derivative at $v$ must be zero?

Comment: @C.Falcon why the derivative at $v$ must be zero?

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on C. Falcon's answer:
For anyone wondering why the derivative at the vertex must be zero; let $c:I \to X$ be a curve such that $c(0)=v$ and $c'(0) \not = 0$. Let $f:I \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be such that $f(t) = \frac{c'(t)}{|c'(t)|}$. By hypothesis, $f$ is well defined and obviously continuous. Now, since $f(t)$ is the (unit) direction of the tangent vector to the square at the point $c(t)$ then, $f(t)$ is equal to the (unit) slope of the side of the square in which $c(t)$ lives. In particular,
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t \to 0^+} f(t) \not = \lim_{t \to 0^-} f(t)
\end{equation}
A contradiction since $f$ is continuous.

P.D. I'm still a newb so any corrections or comments will be greatly appreciated.